# mod_rewrite precedence

Tags: mod-rewrite

Let's say I want to support urls like twitter where:
`twitter.com/username` redirects to `twitter.com/user_name.php?user=username`

I have the following

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user_name.php?user=$1
```

And that works fine.  But the problem is now that everything, including `twitter.com/index.php` will of course redirect to `user_name.php`

How can I either create exceptions or precedence so that "real files" don't get rewritten?  I tried adding an explicit rule for index.php before and after that one, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `RewriteCond` for this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f [OR] # for existing files 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d # for existing directories
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user_name.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Okay, that's MUCH better then my solution -- assuming it works. I've got to try that on a project I have. Could you explain what's actually going on here?

Comment: That doesn't work for me, domain.com/index.php still uses the rewrite rule for user_name.php

Comment: Actually you were pretty close, this works for me: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: Are you sure you want that disjunction? That means only one of the conditions must be fulfilled.